# Making informative legend for Kernel Density Estimate in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, legend, density, kernel-density

I have used heatmap (kernel density estimation) in QGIS 3.0.1 to make a heatmap of boat counts.
In my point data-each point is one boat.
Then, in my kernel, I have used a 500m radius, with 500m pixel size X and Y and uniform kernel shape. (I'm not sure if this is a great idea to have as pixel size...) I left the output as raw.
What I am wondering now, is how to make an informative legend?
The default legend looks like this:
[image]

I think that this means that in red there are 0-1 boats within 500m, in pinky orange: 1.1-9.5 in 500m, etc...

Is this the case?

When I try to change the values manually, the colours go out of order and the largest bracket is stuck in the middle of the key. 

Further, how do I get this info out and use it as a legend in my plot?